# jssor carousel - images are hidden in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, jssor

I started experiencing an issue with images not being displayed on my jssor carousel slider; this issue is only present on Chrome (latest Version 45.0.2454.101 m) - it works fine under Firefox, Explorer and mobile browsers.

Drilling down, it seems that user agent stylesheet adds/applies this element:
transform: perspective(2000px);
When in Chrome's Developer Tools, unchecking this style option results in image being displayed just fine.

Any help with explanation what is going on and how to deal with this issue is much appreciated.

Thank you,
Michael

Comment: There is nothing better than showing your code. Please avoid theoretical question.

Comment: There is nothing better than constructive dialog. Please avoid unnecessary snipes and snubs - community is not better of for it. For those interested, I stumbled on the answer right here at stack overflow. Another user had issues with blurred images in Jssor slider and also experienced >>transform: perspective(2000px);<< issues.  The solution is to set  $HWA option to false.